# Is it safe to disable clamscan and clamd services on linux server

Tags: centos, cpu, clamav, optimization

We have a dedicated CentOS server with 8 CPUs. We often observe clamscan and clamav taking too much CPU. I have heard experts saying linux doesn't require an antivirus. If that is true, is it safe to disable clamscan and clamav completely?

Comment: What is `clamav` used for on your server? Is there an email server? or some cloud service or what is it scanning? `clamav` will usually not scan your system if you don't tell it to do so.

Comment: I run a website with hundreds of static pages and images. I also run email server on the same machine. clamav is scanning the entire home directory apart from emails. Especially, the directory scan is consuming too much memory..

Comment: I'd turn off scanning the home directory. Scanning emails should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virus scanner isn't likely to do much for the local linux machine, but you might be using it to scan uploaded files from OSes that aren't so safe. Or it might be removing evil attachments from email it processes.

I say, humbly, that if you have to ask, you should leave it on.

It is chewing on something, when you see the weight of it, so it might be doing something useful.

Maybe start it with 'nice' or something.

Answer (score 0):

It might be fine to turn off Clamav services, it certainly consumes incresaly resources like cpu and memory. You should instead, use well known services/frameworks that helps to detect and alert on any unauthorized action or access into the server such as Snort or OSSEC.

Comment: But won't disabling Clamav open up any security loophole?

Comment: As you don't know what clamav is used for on OPs server, you should not say that OP can turn it off. And please explain what detecting unauthorized access has to do with antivirus software?

Comment: What do you mean by "OPs server"?. Anyways, clamav it is not the only way to se cure a server, by hardening services and setting up monitoring frameworks like Snort or OSSEC you should be goodnts to to go. *But* as I saw in the comments that there are an email server then clamav should be needed as you don't want useres to send malicious attachments to other mailboxes users.